# jquery how to check if browser tab/window the selected is on our page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do check if a the user has the browser's tab/window currently on our page

```
function userisonourpage()
{
//do something
}
```

And when a user switches the tab/window to our page ?

```
function tabswitched()
{
//dom something here too
}
```

Just like in many places u switch to the page and the title changes i know the title can be changed with : `document.title`
but dont know how to implement those functions.

Thanks :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $([window, document]).focusin(function(){
      //Your logic when the page gets active
   }).focusout(function(){
      //Your logic when the page gets inactive
   });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if the page might be the active tab, but the "focusout" function gets called if you happen to have a different application open and you click on this different application.

Comment: This can be a desirable behaviour, depends on the application needs.

Comment: this is only working on ff.. not on chrome, safari or IE.. is that correct?