# jQuery on tab refocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

How would I detect using JQuery when a user has returned to the webpage. For example, a user opens the webpage in a tab and then changes to another tab to browse a different website. Is there anyway to detect that the user has then returned to your webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question to this problem, which was answered here. Hope this helps you:

[jquery how to check if browser tab/window the selected is on our page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559640/jquery-how-to-check-if-browser-tab-window-the-selected-is-on-our-page)

Answer (score 0):

This example uses Dojo, but both libraries normalize events and can bind listeners:

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/10/13/the-cross-browser-window-focus-blues/